# Don't use the <a> HTML element for things which aren't hyperlinks

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, semantics

Stack Exchange often uses the `<a>` HTML element where it should use the `<button>` element. For example, on the profile page I can sort my answers by "votes", "activity" or "newest":

[image]

The HTML markup for these tabs is as follows:

```
<div class="subtabs user-panel-subtabs">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="youarehere" data-sort-id="votes">votes</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-sort-id="activity">activity</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-sort-id="newest">newest</a>
</div>
```

These should be `<button>`s, not `<a>`s. See [The Difference Between Anchors, Inputs and Buttons](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-buttons) and [Which “href” value to use for JavaScript links: “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134845/3853934)